# Creating an inputbox with radiobuttons c#

Tags: c#, input

I'm currently making a simple C# game for a college assignment, wondering if it's possible to have radio or checkbox (or something similar) inputs upon loading, in an external window.
I'm currently using this to get a username:

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
        GlobalVar.Username = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Welcome to EasiGame, Please enter your username.", "Welcome", "Player1", -1, -1);
        label4.Text = GlobalVar.Username;            
    }
```

This references VB, and that works great, however could I include radio buttons or something in this box, or a separate box, to grab user input for a difficulty setting.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just make your own custom dialog and show it??

Comment: Input box is just that, an input box with only a textbox to type something and there is no other common dialog for this. You need to design your form and call it with ShowDialog, extract your user input and run the other forms

Comment: I've just searched this and doing this makes a lot more sense, and also allows me to make it appear exactly as I want. Thanks, I wasn't aware I could do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have implement your own form. Assuming you're using a recent version of Visual Studio:

1. Click `Project` > `Add Windows Form`.
2. Set the `FormBorderStyle` property of the Form control to `FixedDialog` to prevent
   the user from resizing the form.
3. Set the `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox` properties to false.
4. Set the `StartPosition` property to `CenterScreen` or `CenterParent`.
5. Add a button to the form with the text `OK` and set the `DialogResult`
   property to `OK`.
6. Add a button to the form with the text `Cancel` and set the `DialogResult`
   property to `Cancel`.
7. Change the `AcceptButton` property of the form to reference the `OK` button.
8. Change the `CancelButton` property of the form to reference the `Cancel` button.
9. Add a `TextBox` and a `RadioButton` or `CheckBox` control to the form.
10. Press the `F7` key to open the code view for the form.
11. Implement a property of type `string` that returns the `Text` property of
    the `TextBox` control.
12. You'll also need to come up with a way of getting the difficulty from the
    form; I'll let you figure this part out for yourself :)
13. To show the form, create an instance and call the `ShowDialog()` method.
    This will block the calling method until the user has clicked a button.
    The `ShowDialog` method will return a `DialogResult`, which can be used to
    determine which button was clicked.