# Adding Radio Buttons on a MessageBox/DialogBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, messagebox

Is it possible to add radio buttons on a msgbox/dialog message without creating a form like:

```
MessageBox.Show("Select Option", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that, with Yes/No Buttons I could add a radio buttons at the upper part of the message without creating a new winform/userform.

Let me know if this is achievable then if so please give me any good reference that might help achieve this stuffs.

Comment: You could create a `new form` with all the controls on it that you like? And use that instead of the `msgbox`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an inputbox with radiobuttons c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881812/creating-an-inputbox-with-radiobuttons-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi Mech_Engineer! I want only a MessageBox appear only without creating a new form with a radio.

Comment: Hi! It seems that the reference you gave me doesn't meet my expectations.  Any other reference aside from creating a userform?  Userform cost a lot of memory!

Comment: No, it doesn't "cost a lot of memory". You literally won't be able to measure the memory difference between a MessageBox and a form with a couple of controls on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been suggested, the simple solution is to create your own form and display it using the `ShowModal` method. It will work just like a MessageBox, but you can put any control you want on it.

You don't appear to be satisfied with that. In fact, there is a way to do this with a message box, but it is *way* too complicated. It involves installing a hook that will trigger when the message box is displayed, and then writing a bunch of code that will dynamically add controls and manipulate the layout of the message box. Which will have to be done with a bunch of P/Invoke because the message box is a native Win32 dialog, not a Windows Form. The wrapper classes won't be of any help. Really not worth it. Message boxes aren't designed to be extensible.

Consider using a [Task Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471.aspx) instead. This is almost exactly what they are designed for. Instead of radio buttons, you use a series of command buttons that describe the choices that are available. This is a better UI because only a single click is required to make a choice, rather than two. It would look something like this:

[image]

"Do you want to save your work?" is called the Main Instruction and should be kept very short. Then there's a supplemental instruction underneath it that provides more details, if the user wants to read it. Finally, you have the series of command links that contain a brief and detailed description of what will happen when the user clicks them. In this case, "Save work" and "Don't save".

(The example is a dumb use of a Task Dialog. You should just use regular old buttons for Save/Don't Save. But it was the best example I could find on Google images.)

If you want, you can actually put radio buttons into a Task Dialog:

[image]

In fact, as that image shows, you can pretty much anything you want into a Task Dialog—way too much. It is very customizable. That is the big improvement it offers over the venerable old MessageBox API.

There is a .NET wrapper for the Task Dialog API available [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=180615).

Comment: Thanks for the great reply Cody Gray!  This reference will be a great help to achieve with my software.  Thanks a lot!